# How to manipulate response status in deadbolt onAuthFailure

Tags: java, angularjs, httpresponse, deadbolt-2

I'm using deadbolt library for authentication in my playframewrok server app which holds api for some other frontend application. In MyDeadboltHandler class in 
onAuthFailure method when user isn't authenticated I want to return status 403 with next piece of code:

```
@Override
public F.Promise<Result> onAuthFailure(Http.Context context, String content) {
    return F.Promise.pure(unauthorized("Authentication Failed"));
}
```

however in my frontend application (Angular 1.5) in my error handler Im getting response which is some generic error with error status code -1
How can I change my method this to get normal 403 error status in response?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds more like a value emitted from Angular itself.  If you use developer tools in your browser, you should see the incoming response and it should be a 401 (unauthorized).  From here, you should be able to find the Angular code that's dealing with this.

You should also consider varying the response based on whether a subject is present.  If a subject is present, return a 403; if a subject isn't present, return a 401.